# MPMoviePlayerController restarting instead of resuming

Tags: ios, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to have MPMoviePlayerController reach a programmed endPlaybackTime, then reassign the initial, current, and end times and "resume" play

So first play, say, from the start to 4 seconds, stop/pause, then resume and play from 4 to 8, etc...

but after I reassign current, initial, and endPlaybackTimes and run [mplayer play], the video restarts from the originally times (start to 4s) and plays to the original end time, even though debug messages confirm the new times after the second play

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
_mplayer3 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
_mplayer3.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[_mplayer3.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view insertSubview:_mplayer3.view belowSubview:_TopBrag];
_mplayer3.endPlaybackTime = 4.0;
[_mplayer3 setShouldAutoplay:NO];
[_mplayer3 prepareToPlay];
[_mplayer3 view].userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(parallaxDownDidFinish)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_mplayer3];
[_mplayer3 play];
```

on the end notification, there's a gesture recognizer is created that appears to work correctly.  in the gesture recognizer:

```
_mplayer3.initialPlaybackTime=_mplayer3.endPlaybackTime;
_mplayer3.currentPlaybackTime=_mplayer3.endPlaybackTime;
_mplayer3.endPlaybackTime+=4.0;
if (_mplayer3.endPlaybackTime > _mplayer3.duration)
    _mplayer3.endPlaybackTime = _mplayer3.duration;
[_mplayer3 play]
```

and the video plays from 0 to 4 instead of 4 to 8, even though NSLogs after the play suggest the times are what's desired

appreciate any help

Comment: [_mplayer3 pause] to resume

Comment: thank you but pause only paused it (did not resume playing)

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerController` does not adhere to the `initialPlaybackTime` if not used on a fresh instance. You will need to release and realloc/assign the player to get this working. All you need to do is to reuse the initial code shown in your question once the player aught to continue.

---

Update:

Since you seem to be keen on keeping the player view active and as you are not using the standard user interface, I would suggest you to use `AVPlayer` instead. It is much more flexible and for your job it seems to be the right choice then.

Comment: thanks this is good work around but reallocating a new video player would ruin the aesthetic in this instance, and not prepared to mask transition with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats the problem, because it should work, the problem i think is that you are in IOS 6, IOS 6 doesn't let you make such a small change, but if in your swipe you change the initial playtime to 9 or higher it should work....

try it and then let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this did not seem to work.  Since my video in question is about 12s long, I put in a sample video and tested over a few different parameters, including first endPlaybackTime of 10s, increasing in increments of 10s, trying play/pause (above), and with/without initialPlaybackTime (below).

Comment: I also explored how the player is first stared with [_mplayer3 prepareToPlay] for example, but the only behavior I've gotten is to restart from the beginning and play the same [0, first endPLaybackTime] interval

Comment: I tested to this pourpouse and i figured out the answer i told you.... try and test with a video of 30 second longer... and test how I told you...